# Generating new model by altering existing metadata in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, metadata, feature-dataset

I've got a metadata set for a specific geographic area (A).  The datasets used in the metadata are all based on generic data.

Is it possible to generate a similar model for a different geographic area (B) using the same metadata?

How would I go about replacing the datasets from area A with that of area B?

I'm fairly new to GIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve may be the reverse i.e. importing area A's metadata to Area B's dataset.

If you're using ArcGIS Desktop, then you can do this in ArcCatalog. Click on the description for feature B and click import. If Area A's metadata was created also in ArcGIS Desktop, you can use "Import Type" "From Arcgis". This will preserve Field descriptions. If not, you can use any of the standards listed that your Area A's metadata uses. After running the tool, you can make edits to Area B's new metadata.